# Porque um dos casos estão incorretos?

Tags: c

Boa noite, gostaria de saber, o porque do meu codigo retornar um valor errado para um caso no qual a entrada é 1,1 e 100000, a saida deveria dar 100000 e 5000050000 e esta dando 100000 e 705082704??a saida deveria ser double ou float??

```
#include <stdio.h> //Bibliteca para as fuÃ±coes de entrada e saida

int main (void) //Programa principal

{
    int a1, r, n, An, Sn; //Declaracao das variaveis necessarias 
    scanf("%d\n%d\n%d",&a1, &r, &n); //Insercao dos valores de A1, r e n

    An = a1+(n-1)*r; //Formula para encontrar o enesimo termo da PA
    printf("%d\n", An); //Impressao na tela do valor do enesimo termo encontrado

    Sn = (a1+An)*n/2; //Formula para fazer a soma dos "n" termos da PA
    printf("%d", Sn); //Impressao na tela do valor da soma da PA

return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Porque ultrapassaste os limites para `int` do teu computador.

`5000050000` é mais que 2^31-1 (`2147483647`).
O teu programa sofre de Comportamente Indefenido.

---

```
5000050000(10) == 100101010000001101011010101010000(2) // 33 bits
                   00101010000001101011010101010000(2) = 705082704(10)
```

Comment: E como eu posso resolver esse problema??

Comment: Podes usar um tipo de dados com limites superiores (`long` por exemplo), ou, se tencionas usar numeros realmente grandes (com milhares de bits) usar uma [biblioteca bignum](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bignum) ([artigo em ingles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic)).

Answer (score 0):

Na verdade o limite realmente ultrapassa o dos inteiros usuais. Basta troca-los por `long`s

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    long a1, r, n, An, Sn; 
    scanf("%ld %ld %ld",&a1, &r, &n); 

    An = a1 + (n - 1) * r; 
    printf("%ld\n", An); 

    Sn = (a1 + An) * n/2; 
    printf("%ld\n", Sn); 

    return 0;
}
```